# how define elements type in attributes type array of gutenberg blocks

Tags: block-editor

How i can define type of elements of array attribute?

```
attributes: {    
  list: {
    type: 'array',
    default: []
  }
}
```

For example

```
attributes: {    
  list: {
    type: 'array',
    default: [],
    typesInArray: {
      first: {
        type: 'string'
      },
      second: {
        type: 'number'
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `source: query` for it.

From [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#query-source):

> Use query to extract an array of values from markup. Entries of the array are determined by the selector argument, where each matched element within the block will have an entry structured corresponding to the second argument, an object of attribute sources.
>
> The query field is effectively a nested block attributes definition. It is possible (although not necessarily recommended) to nest further.
>
> Example: Extract src and alt from each image element in the block’s markup.
>
> Saved content:
>
> ```
> <div>
>     <img src="https://lorempixel.com/1200/800/" alt="large image" />
>     <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="small image" />
> </div>
> ```
>
> Attribute definition:
>
> ```
> {
>     images: {
>         type: 'array',
>         source: 'query',
>         selector: 'img',
>         query: {
>             url: {
>                 type: 'string',
>                 source: 'attribute',
>                 attribute: 'src',
>             },
>             alt: {
>                 type: 'string',
>                 source: 'attribute',
>                 attribute: 'alt',
>             },
>         }
>     } }
> ```
>
> Attribute available in the block:
>
> ````
>     "images": [
>         { "url": "https://lorempixel.com/1200/800/", "alt": "large image" },
>         { "url": "https://lorempixel.com/50/50/", "alt": "small image" }
>     ] } ```
> ````